# light and camera icons missing

Tags: camera, light

Both my camera and light are completely missing. They don't appear on the 3D View and the icons are not on the outliner under the "scene" collection where they would normally be. I tried pressing 0 to look through the camera but nothing happens. Does anyone know how to bring them back?

[[image]
[[image]

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: You just need to add them back . Press Shift + A select the camera and then Shift + A and select the light... Also make sure that they are not inside the collection "Archive" that is turn it off

Comment: It looks like you either removed them, then you can just add them back like the previous comment or maybe you put them in your "archive" collection, try to un-exclude it and see if its in there.